# How to remove DIV from Facebook "I LIKE" plugin?

Tags: facebook-like

Does it possible to remove head DIV (that holds name, ico and I like ) from Facebook "I LIKE" plugin?
I would like to have only clean "facebook story stream" on our web page.

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, embed the code like normal and then put this in

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
```

EDIT*** obviously the width, change it to whatever you need it to be

Comment: Im sorry, Im not sure I have explained well what I mean. So I made screenshot http://s14.postimage.org/kg6z4zapt/Ilike.gif I would like to remove all in red ellipse.